# .htacces to Nginx rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I need some help with a conversion to nginx for this .htaccess rewrite rule.

`RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` is a standard front controller pattern, e.g. you have a single bootstrap PHP file which handles requests for SEO friendly URLs.

In NGINX, the standard practice is using `try_files` directive for that pattern, like so:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

The above corresponds to the bottom 3 lines of your config:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

The topmost lines do not need converting to NGINX, because those are already the default in NGINX:

- rewrite module is enabled
- symbolic links are followed
- directory listing is off